# Пустые массивы в java, проверка на пустоту

Tags: java, массивы

В одном из заданий в курсе было написать программу, которая принимает массив целых чисел в аргументы метода и возвращает массив с наименьшим и наибольшим числом. Но также было условие, что если входной массив пустой, то возвращать должно два нуля. В примерах: getStatistic({}) == {0, 0}. Вопрос такой: что использовать для проверки массива на эту "пустоту", чтобы при введении пустого массива при вызове метода возвращались нули?

С числами всё супер, но когда массив пустой, то выдаёт ошибку ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, что вроде бы логично, ведь массив пустой, но я всё равно не понимаю, что можно добавить или изменить в этом коде, чтобы условие с пустыми массивами было выполнено. Хелпаните, пожалуйста.

P.S. Насколько помню я, пустой массив - тот, где задано количество обьектов в нём, но не проинициализировано их, все обьекты равны нулю. Поправьте, если я путаю, пожалуйста.

```java
public static int[] getStatistic(int[] results) {
    int max = results[0];
    int min = results[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        if (results[i] < min) {
            min = results[i];
        }
        if (results[i] > max) {
            max = results[i];
        }
    }
    int[] array = {
        min,
        max
    };
    return array;
}
```

Comment: Ноль, конечно, в некотором смысле пустое место, но не в программировании. Отвыкайте думать, что а) ноль - значит непроинициализировано, б) непроинициализировано - значит ноль.

Answer (score 2):

Если массив пустой, то он не содержит некоторое число неиниц. объектов, он **вообще ничего не содержит**. Пример: `{}`

Чтобы проверить массив на пустоту, можно сравнить его длину с нулём. Для этого мы используем метод массива `length`, возвращающий число объектов массива.

```java
...
if (results.length == 0) {
    return new int[] {0, 0}; // быстрое объявление массива
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int[] getStatistic(int[] results) {
  int max = 0;
  int min = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
      min = result[i];
      max = result[i];
    } else {
      if (results[i] < min) {
        min = results[i];
      }
      if (results[i] > max) {
        max = results[i];
      }
    }
  }
  int[] array = {
    min,
    max
  };
  return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В существующем коде следовало изменить инициализацию минимума/максимума и добавить проверку на первый элемент массива.

Тогда цикл `for` не будет выполняться для пустого массива, так как не выполнится строгое условие `i < 0`:

```java
public static int[] getStatistic(int[] results) {
    int max = 0;
    int min = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        if (results[i] < min || i == 0) {
            min = results[i];
        }
        if (results[i] > max || i == 0) {
            max = results[i];
        }
    }
    return new int[]{min, max};
}
```